# complete learning plan for student

Tags: self-learning, learning

I'm  a computer science student and I'm lacking in maths. I want to improve myself however I have trouble looking for a math learning plan. I'm aware my question is not quite specific and that a learning plan strongly differ following what your ultimate goal is but I dont have one, I want to learn as much as I can but the main problem is I didn't manage to find something adapted to me. By that I mean either things are too advanced for me and thus require too learn other things before or the opposite (too basic). In fact the main issue is I don't know the name of maths fields (and it's quite hard to find something without knowing it's name).

So my question is, what are math fields sorted by croissant difficulty order ?

Edit : 
One path is not an obligation and cannot be fullfilled, I'm looking for multiple path in multiple fields and those path are not required to be linked with computer science. 
 
I can't tell what I know because I don't know either, I have a bit of knowledge in a lot of thing but not enough to say I know things, I want to restart from the basics and then expand it further (and again I'm aware my question is hard to answer because my vagueness).

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's a very algebraic path. I'd recommend a more balanced path, but to each their own.

Comment: If everything you are finding is either too basic or too advanced, it's quite likely that the basic stuff isn't as basic as you imagine it to be. I wouldn't say math has a difficulty order, but rather a hierarchy of necessary things to know before addressing topics.

Comment: I agree with @DonThousand, but its my fault for not being clear enought, I'm not looking for one path but for multiple ones with each step (of every path) being more in-depth.

Comment: And by too basic or advanced I was refering to the ressources I found on internet. It's hard without specific name to find what I'm looking for and either I'm finding post graduate course or hight-school one.

Comment: Typical topics might include linear algebra, set theory, logic, combinatorics, number theory, calculus/real analysis, geometry, numerical methods, probability/statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undergraduate study in computer science will require discrete mathematics, linear algebra,(probably) calculus and (perhaps) probability.

You can look at textbooks in each of these areas (many available on line) and see what things there you do not understand. Then go back and learn those things.

The main prerequisite for this material is solid knowledge of elementary algebra and precalculus.

Without knowing a lot more about what you know and how you are studying (alone? at school?) I can't see how to provide anything like a "complete learning plan."